# Change git remote head pointer to a commit

Tags: git

How can I change the git remote head pointer to a commit? I pushed some commits to remote master branch, which I have local reverted with:

```
git reset --hard COMMIT_SHA
```

Now, I want that the remote head points to the commit `COMMIT_SHA`. How can I do that?

I found:

- [Make git master HEAD point to current HEAD of branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271938/make-git-master-head-point-to-current-head-of-branch)
- [How does origin/HEAD get set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839958/how-does-origin-head-get-set)

but I don't know, if that is what I need in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If forcing a push isn't possible, you can try and make a new commit on top of your current master (the one before any `reset --hard`)

```
git reset --hard COMMIT_SHA
git reset --soft @{1}  # (or ORIG_HEAD)
git commit -a
```

You can then push that *additional* commit which reflect the content of `COMMIT_SHA`.

---

Regarding the non-fast-forward error message, I would recommend to pull first (or to fetch, and `reset --hard origin/master`).

Then, once your `master` branch reflects the upstream one, you can do the additional commit I describe above, and push it *without* having to use `--force`.

Comment: Does not work: `$ git push --force gitlab master
Counting objects: 60, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
Writing objects: 100% (40/40), 4.72 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 40 (delta 26), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first
)
To git@ip:development/project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@ip:development/project.g
it'`

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE the point of my answer is to create an additional commit that you can **push without --force**

Comment: Yes I have done: `$ git reset --hard COMMIT_SHA
HEAD is now at 842d732 updated search functions
$ git reset --soft @{1}
$ git commit -am "reset remote head pointer to commit COMMIT_SHA"`, before I tried without `--force`, but it does also not work.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE what is the error message you have when pushing without `--force`? Are you pushing to a repo that you own? That you are authorized to push to?

Comment: Error without `--force`: `$ git push gitlab master
To git@ip:development/project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@ip:development/project.g
it'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
` Yes, I'm authorized.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE Ok, I have edited my answer to address that error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git push --force` to force what you have to the remote.

Take care that nobody is using the code that you've pushed in the meantime, though.

Comment: I already tried that, but I get an error.: `$ git push --force gitlab master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first
)
To git@ip:development/project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@ip:development/project.g
it'`